# Rotação de imagem em java

Tags: java, imagem, processamento-de-imagens

Estou precisando de um algoritmo para girar uma imagem em java. Na internet eu achei um algoritmo promissor [neste link](http://edroidx.blogspot.com.br/2010/12/rotate-and-translate-images-with.html), e dei uma arrumada nele e adaptei para utilizar ângulos em graus. Ficou assim:

```java
public static BufferedImage rotateImage(BufferedImage rotateImage, double angle) {
    AffineTransform tx = new AffineTransform();
    tx.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle), rotateImage.getWidth() / 2.0, rotateImage.getHeight() / 2.0);

    double ytrans = tx.transform(new Point2D.Double(0.0, 0.0), null).getY();
    double xtrans = tx.transform(new Point2D.Double(0, rotateImage.getHeight()), null).getX();

    AffineTransform translationTransform = new AffineTransform();
    translationTransform.translate(-xtrans, -ytrans);
    tx.preConcatenate(translationTransform);

    return new AffineTransformOp(tx, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR).filter(rotateImage, null);
}
```

No entanto, este método não funciona corretamente para ângulos maiores do que 90 graus (e provavelmente para menores que -90 também). Resolvi isso com uma gambiarra que depende de uma imagem intermediária:

```java
public static BufferedImage rotateImage(BufferedImage rotateImage, double angle) {
    angle %= 360;
    if (angle < 0) angle += 360;
    int quadrants = (int) angle / 90;
    double restAngle = angle % 90;
    if (restAngle < 0) restAngle += 90;

    AffineTransform tx = new AffineTransform();
    tx.rotate(Math.toRadians(restAngle), rotateImage.getWidth() / 2.0, rotateImage.getHeight() / 2.0);

    double ytrans = tx.transform(new Point2D.Double(0.0, 0.0), null).getY();
    double xtrans = tx.transform(new Point2D.Double(0, rotateImage.getHeight()), null).getX();

    AffineTransform translationTransform = new AffineTransform();
    translationTransform.translate(-xtrans, -ytrans);
    tx.preConcatenate(translationTransform);

    BufferedImage b2 = new AffineTransformOp(tx, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR).filter(rotateImage, null);

    AffineTransform fix = AffineTransform.getQuadrantRotateInstance(
            quadrants, b2.getWidth() / 2.0, b2.getHeight() / 2.0);
    return new AffineTransformOp(fix, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR).filter(b2, null);
}
```

<s>Funcionou.</s> No entanto, eu sei que é possível resolver isso sem precisar de uma imagem intermediária. Já quebrei bastante a cabeça e não consigo fazer isso funcionar de um jeito melhor, só tive imagens cortadas e deformadas como resultado. Alguém tem uma ideia?

Edit: Achei um bug: Ele não funciona corretamente para imagens que não forem quadradas, e eu não sei porquê.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pelo que eu testei aqui, assim funciona:

```
public static BufferedImage rotateImage(BufferedImage rotateImage, double angle) {
    angle %= 360;
    if (angle < 0) angle += 360;

    AffineTransform tx = new AffineTransform();
    tx.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle), rotateImage.getWidth() / 2.0, rotateImage.getHeight() / 2.0);

    double ytrans = 0;
    double xtrans = 0;
    if( angle <= 90 ){
        xtrans = tx.transform(new Point2D.Double(0, rotateImage.getHeight()), null).getX();
        ytrans = tx.transform(new Point2D.Double(0.0, 0.0), null).getY();
    }
    else if( angle <= 180 ){
        xtrans = tx.transform(new Point2D.Double(rotateImage.getWidth(), rotateImage.getHeight()), null).getX();
        ytrans = tx.transform(new Point2D.Double(0, rotateImage.getHeight()), null).getY();
    }
    else if( angle <= 270 ){
        xtrans = tx.transform(new Point2D.Double(rotateImage.getWidth(), 0), null).getX();
        ytrans = tx.transform(new Point2D.Double(rotateImage.getWidth(), rotateImage.getHeight()), null).getY();
    }
    else{
        xtrans = tx.transform(new Point2D.Double(0, 0), null).getX();
        ytrans = tx.transform(new Point2D.Double(rotateImage.getWidth(), 0), null).getY();
    }

    AffineTransform translationTransform = new AffineTransform();
    translationTransform.translate(-xtrans, -ytrans);
    tx.preConcatenate(translationTransform);

    return new AffineTransformOp(tx, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR).filter(rotateImage, null);
}
```

Segue uma imagem para ajudar a entender a lógica:
[image: Rotação]

Comment: Ok, gostei da resposta. Infelizmente eu não posso aceitar as duas respostas, então vou pensar um pouquinho para decidir qual eu aceito.

Answer (score 13):

A resposta do @RodrigodeBonaSartor funciona perfeitamente e a grande sacada é que o algoritmo faz um ajuste considerando os cantos da imagem que são "escondidos" após a rotação, como forma a evitar que a imagem seja truncada nessas regiões.

O gráfico da própria resposta do Rodrigo ajuda bastante nesse entendimento, mas vou tentar explicar com um pouco mais de detalhes. Vou usar como exemplo a seguinte imagem (quadrada) da [Lenna](http://gizmodo.uol.com.br/como-uma-coelhinha-da-playboy-entrou-para-a-historia-da-tecnologia/):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A rotação é uma operação que simplesmente transforma cada pixel da imagem segundo um ângulo dado (veja [essa página da Wikipedia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rota%C3%A7%C3%A3o_%28matem%C3%A1tica%29) para mais informações). Ao se aplicar uma rotação de 45º sem fazer a translação de ajuste, o resultado faz com que o canto superior esquerdo (coordenada `(0,0)`) e o canto inferior esquerdo (coordenada `(0, height)`) sejam posicionados *fora da área original da imagem*, produzindo o seguinte resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Um código como...

```java
Point2D ponto = tx.transform(new Point2D.Double(rotateImage.getWidth(), 0.0), null);
```

...simplesmente mapeia o ponto original (no exemplo acima, `(width, 0)`) segundo a transformação descrita por `tx` (que poderia ter uma série de transformações concatenadas - o resultado seria o mapeamento final após todas as transformações sobre o ponto). Note que no código dessa pergunta isso é equivalente a calcular a rotação do ponto (`x' = x * cosseno(angulo) - y * seno(angulo), y' = x * seno(angulo) + y * cosseno(angulo)`), uma vez que a transformação `tx` inclui apenas uma rotação.

Com um ângulo de 45º, a rotação de cada canto da imagem produz os seguintes resultados:

```java
Point2D.Double(0.0, 0.0) => Point2D.Double[127.99999999999999, -53.01933598375615]
Point2D.Double(rotateImage.getWidth(), 0.0) => Point2D.Double[309.01933598375615, 128.0]
Point2D.Double(0.0, rotateImage.getHeight()) => Point2D.Double[-53.019335983756164, 128.00000000000003]
Point2D.Double(rotateImage.getWidth(), rotateImage.getHeight()) => Point2D.Double[128.0, 309.01933598375615]
```

Como na linguagem Java o sistema de coordenadas tem origem (coordenada `(0,0)`) no canto superior esquerdo, pode-se observar que os cantos "escondidos" (isto é, fora da área original da imagem por estarem à esquerda ou acima da origem) tem coordenadas mapeadas em valor negativo. Isso vale tanto para o eixo X como para o eixo Y.

Assim, o que o algoritmo proposto pelo Rodrigo faz é simplesmente verificar quais cantos estão "escondidos" (de acordo com o intervalo do ângulo dado) e calcular a diferença de translação por eixo de forma a "mover" os cantos excondidos para o limite visível da imagem (isto é, para próximo da origem `(0,0)`). É uma sacada simples, e que funciona.

Porém, para tornar o código um pouco mais enxuto (e, potencialmente, mais simples de entender), basta calcular a rotação para os quatro cantos da imagem e escolher, dentre os resultados, os menores valores negativos para os eixos X e Y.

Eis um exemplo:

```java
public static BufferedImage rotateImage(BufferedImage rotateImage, double angle) {
    AffineTransform tx = new AffineTransform();
    tx.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle), rotateImage.getWidth() / 2.0, rotateImage.getHeight() / 2.0);

    // Rotaciona as coordenadas dos cantos da imagem
    Point2D[] aCorners = new Point2D[4];
    aCorners[0] = tx.transform(new Point2D.Double(0.0, 0.0), null);
    aCorners[1] = tx.transform(new Point2D.Double(rotateImage.getWidth(), 0.0), null);
    aCorners[2] = tx.transform(new Point2D.Double(0.0, rotateImage.getHeight()), null);
    aCorners[3] = tx.transform(new Point2D.Double(rotateImage.getWidth(), rotateImage.getHeight()), null);

    // Obtém o valor de translação para cada eixo com um canto "escondido"
    double dTransX = 0;
    double dTransY = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if(aCorners[i].getX() < 0 && aCorners[i].getX() < dTransX)
            dTransX = aCorners[i].getX();
        if(aCorners[i].getY() < 0 && aCorners[i].getY() < dTransY)
            dTransY = aCorners[i].getY();
    }

    // Aplica a translação para evitar cortes na imagem
    AffineTransform translationTransform = new AffineTransform();
    translationTransform.translate(-dTransX, -dTransY);
    tx.preConcatenate(translationTransform);

    return new AffineTransformOp(tx, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR).filter(rotateImage, null);
}
```

Tal como na resposta do Rodrigo, esse algoritmo também ajusta corretamente a imagem para evitar recortes:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No caso da imagem de exemplo anterior, é fácil notar que o montante necessário de translação é o mesmo tanto no eixo X como no eixo Y (53 pixels aproximadamente), mas isso se deve ao ângulo utilizado (45º) e ao fato da imagem ser quadrada. Como o algoritmo proposto faz a verificação dos montantes individualmente por eixo, funciona corretamente para outros exemplos, como abaixo (rotação de 260º e imagem retangular - note que há dois valores negatívos para o eixo Y, mas o algoritmo escolhe o menor = -104 aproximadamente):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```java
Point2D.Double(0.0, 0.0) => Point2D.Double[123.93876331951267, 328.9969705899713]
Point2D.Double(rotateImage.getWidth(), 0.0) => Point2D.Double[54.47949225274054, -64.92613061491193]
Point2D.Double(0.0, rotateImage.getHeight()) => Point2D.Double[345.52050774725944, 289.926130614912]
Point2D.Double(rotateImage.getWidth(), rotateImage.getHeight()) => Point2D.Double[276.06123668048735, -103.99697058997123]
```

> Translação necessária: em X = [0.0], em Y = [-103.99697058997123]

Comment: Ok, gostei da resposta. Infelizmente eu não posso aceitar as duas respostas, então vou pensar um pouquinho para decidir qual eu aceito.

Comment: Valeu. Eu só ofereci uma explicação adicional. A ideia original do algoritmo é do @RodrigodeBonaSartor. :)